# Error: Spring Application Cannot be resolved

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I trying to create Gradle project to use with spring Boot in Eclipse in my organization network. But I am not able to create it It's giving me an error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
SpringApplication cannot be resolved at com.vidya.BootGradleApplication.main(BootGradleApplication.java:11)"
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I have attached the Image for more understanding

[image: 1]

Comment: It looks like dependent spring jars are not downloaded, so you still have compile time errors.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. anyhow I managed to resolve the error. It was due to the configuration of eclipse with the gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else with this problem, here's something important that may help you.

"Eclipse does not automatically update the classpath, if the build.gradle file is updated. Select Gradle ▸ Refresh Gradle Project from the context menu of the project or from your build.gradle file for that"

From http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html#updating-classpath-with-the-latest-changes-in-the-build-file

Answer (score 2):

I am using Vscode and this problem wasted me for an hour.

The way to solve this bug in Vscode is just to restart Vscode so that it can update the project

Comment: I've tried this and even that doesn't work to have it realize that spring exists. If you're doing Spring development, just use IntellJ and save yourself time and frustration